# How to add different prefixes at the beginning for different lines in a file

Tags: perl, unix

My file has following lines:

```
hello
hi
hey
```

I want to use Perl to print letter `A` at the beginning of the first line, letter `B` for the second line, letter `C` for the third line and so on.

My expected output is:

```
A hello
B hi
C hey
```

and so on..

I tried the following:

```
perl -pe 's/^/A/' input.file
```

This probably will insert only 'A' at the beginning of every line in the file. This doesn't meet my requirement.

I am not sure how to handle different prefixes for different lines.

Comment: Is this a homework question? You are welcome to ask about homework, but the answers that you get should be better tuned to your purpose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Increment works for strings, too:

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN { $ch = "A" } print $ch++, " "' < input_file
```

(if `AA` is what follows `Z`).

Or, if `[` follows `Z`, you can use the `$.` variable (input line number):

```
perl -pe 'print chr 64 + $., " "' < input_file
```

Comment: I ended up with `perl -pe "print $c = $c ? ++$c : 'A', ' '" input.file` but it's too golfy for a real answer. No need for the `<` though